# How to pass parameter in url? pl. explain with example?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, react-router, frontend

How to pass parameter in url (suppose i have form in page and on clicking submit hidden  content"thanks "is shown but i want if user refreshes the page on thanks  it should still be shown thanks rather then going back on form page ?

Comment: WHEN THANKS IS SHOWN ALL THE OTHER CONTENT OF WEBPAGE DISAPPEARS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sessionStorage to store form status

```js
// initial status - FALSE
sessionStorage.formStatus = 'false';

// use this code on button click event
sessionStorage.formStatus = 'true';

// check form status and render
if (sessionStorage.formStatus === 'false') {
    // render form
}

if (sessionStorage.formStatus === 'true') {
    // render thank you text
}
```

Comment: can u pl. explain using a form and submit button

Comment: please provide me with your code and I'll make fixes for you